# Question about template and virtual class runtime type

Tags: c++, templates, virtual-functions

I am writing an interpreter with C++ and met some language problem.

I have a class called `ValuableAST`, which is a pure virtual class.

```
class ValuableAST
{
public:
    virtual ~ValuableAST() = default;
    virtual bool is_checked() const
    {
        return false;
    }

    enum class ValueType
    {
        INTEGER,
        REAL
    };

    virtual std::variant<int, double> value() const = 0;
};
```

Here `is_checked` is always false because I will do semantic type checking for all nodes whose type is a derived class of `ValuableAST`.

For example, I have a `Number` class:

```
class Number : public ValuableAST
{
private:
    std::variant<int, double> value_;

public:
    std::variant<int, double> value() const
    {
        return value_;
    }

    explicit Number(int value) : value_(value) {}

    explicit Number(double value) : value_(value) {}

    explicit Number(Number *number) : value_(number->value()) {}
};
```

And then, I want to wrap classes like `Number` after I doing type checking at runtime. So I use template to do that:

```
template <class T>
    requires std::is_base_of_v<ValuableAST, T>
class TypeChecked
    : public T
{
private:
    ValuableAST::ValueType type_;

public:
    explicit TypeChecked(ValuableAST::ValueType type, T *value)
        : T(value), type_(type) {}

    ValuableAST::ValueType type() const { return type_; }

    bool is_checked() const override { return true; }

    int get_int() const
    {
        if (type_ == ValuableAST::ValueType::INTEGER)
        {
            return std::get<int>(this->value());
        }
        else
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Type error");
        }
    }

    double get_real() const
    {
        if (type_ == ValuableAST::ValueType::REAL)
        {
            return std::get<double>(this->value());
        }
        else
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Type error");
        }
    }
};
```

Now I have a function `function_accepting_valuable_ast`, who accepts a parameter of a pointer to `ValuableAST`. I want to implement that in this function, I can generate the `TypeChecked` object based on the real type of the object which the parameter is pointing to:

```
void function_accepting_valuable_ast(ValuableAST *ast)
{
    // generate the type-checked AST object of the given AST object
    // If ast is a Number object, then the generate object is a TypeChecked<Number> object.
    // If ast is another object like a UnaryOperation, I need a TypeChecked<UnaryOperation> object

    const auto type_checked_ast = ...;
}
```

However, here we do not know the real type of `ast` and I cannot generate the corresponding object, I'm stuck here and want to seek any better practice for this scenario.

Comment: `type_checked_ast` would have to be a `std::variant<TypeChecked<Number>, TypeChecked<UnaryOperation>>` since there's runtime polymorphism here.

Comment: `enum class ValueType` is not needed, `std::variant` knows its type.

Comment: Re: "which is a pure virtual class" -- any class that has at least one **pure virtual function** is an **abstract class**.

Comment: Would it make sense to put function_accepting_valuable_ast into class TypeChecked, probably as a virtual function.?  Then its body would have access to T.